# I want to create a int variable that doesn't loose its value after closing my app

Tags: android

I want to create a int variable that doesn't loses its value after closing my app 
with the use of internet.

Comment: Then you have to persist your value somewhere outside of the app and read the value from that storage when the app is run again.  A *variable* by itself (or any in-memory storage in an application) doesn't persist when the application is closed.  The most common place to persist data is in a database.

Comment: For such little data as a single variable (or a few ones), SharedPreferences is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack overflow.
Put your variable value in a database or put in shared preference in android. Then when you back on your app after closing just retrieve the value again and assign it to your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

then save like this:

```
prefs.edit().putInt("your_key", intValue).apply();
```

and read like this:

```
int value = prefs.getInt("your_key", defaultIntValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **shared preferences**. Its quite easy and is under saving key values pair on the android documentation page [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final int variable_name =4;
```

Or if you want the value as changing each time of your request or any calculation

```
public/private static int variable_name=1;
```